# Creating new columns based on existing columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

This is a sample of my dataframe. It comes from a survey where the original question was: "Where are you located? Mark all that apply."

```
Code   Option1   Option2   Option3   Option4
101        A        C         NA        NA
102        B        D         NA        NA
103        A        B         D         NA
104        D        NA        NA        NA
105        A        B         C         D
```

I would like to transform this data so that each column is one of the locations and you get a 0/1 if you're located in any of the 4 locations:

```
Code   A   B   C   D
101    1   0   1   0
102    0   1   0   1
103    1   1   0   1
104    0   0   0   1
105    1   1   1   1
```

I tried using ifelse statements, but I kept getting errors. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -Code, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(n = 1) %>% 
    select(-name) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    select(Code, LETTERS[1:4])
#   Code A B C D
#1  101 1 0 1 0
#2  102 0 1 0 1
#3  103 1 1 0 1
#4  104 0 0 0 1
#5  105 1 1 1 1
```

---

Or using `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1[1], +(mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1[-1]))) > 0))
```

---

Or using `melt/dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), id.var = 'Code', na.rm = TRUE), Code ~ value, length)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this while converting True/False survey responses to binary 1,0 using gsub:

```
t <- function(x) gsub("A",1,x)
f <- function(x) gsub("B",0,x)

df[1:4] <- lapply(df[1:4], t)
df[1:4] <- lapply(df[1:4], f)
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'df1' is your table, this approach takes a few more lines but is easy to understand:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

df1 %>% 
  gather(Code) %>% 
  dcast(Code ~ value, fun.aggregate=length) %>%
  select(-'NA')
```

Your result is:

```
  Code A B C D
1  101 1 0 1 0
2  102 0 1 0 1
3  103 1 1 0 1
4  104 0 0 0 1
5  105 1 1 1 1
```